# Excel VBA - Copy Ranges to Non Empty Rows

Tags: vba, excel

Im looking on how to copy ranges of data until non blank/empty rows. For example i have list of data on column A until G. I want to copy data on those ranges until the last rows. I have code that can find the last row as below:

```
    Sheets("REFS").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Select
    Rows(Selection.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("TP1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: first find the time to comment on previous questions you posted, and give  feedback

Comment: @ShaiRado which one? cause i check mostly i tick as answer or commented myself if i found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. I tested here and it seems to work

```
Sub CopyAllRows()
   Dim j As Long

   Dim refs As Worksheet
   Set refs = Sheets("REFS")

   Dim tp1 As Worksheet
   Set tp1 = Sheets("TP1")

   Dim src As Variant

   j = refs.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row
   src = refs.Range("A1:G" & j).Value
   tp1.Range("A2:G" & j + 1).Value = src

End Sub
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, there was a `Dim i as Long` but that isnt used. You can remove that. I edited the post to fix the code

Comment: No problem. Figured it out.