# VBA custom add new values to Combobox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

My VBA code selects two categories based on a range that I have in a worksheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
   Sheets(1).Activate
   MsgBox "Welcome to the Work Tracker " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Developed by ME"

   frmItemList.cmbCategory.List = Sheets("cmb").Range("A1:A2").Value
   frmItemList.cmbMonth.List = Sheets("cmb").Range("B1:B12").Value
   frmItemList.cmbDay.List = Sheets("cmb").Range("C1:C31").Value
   frmItemList.cmbYear.List = Sheets("cmb").Range("D1:D11").Value 
End Sub
```

I want to take the combobox (cmbCategory) and have it that when people add their own categories, it adds to cell A3 and the range dynamically increases to include the next value.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want it to dynamically change the combobox? Like with the sheet open, you add a new line and it detects the change? Because the way it is setup right now it will only populate when you open the sheet.

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna change the event handler as soon as I figure this out.

Comment: This is another question similar to what you needed. It had a dynamic range. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180948/excel-vba-copy-ranges-to-non-empty-rows/41181409#41181409

Comment: Okay thank you. That solution seems to be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Copy Ranges to Non Empty Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180948/excel-vba-copy-ranges-to-non-empty-rows)